# How generate container page in English language in opencms8.5

Tags: opencms

I am new in opencms.I am working on application of opencms8.5 . Actually my application already developed in struts and spring and now i have to integrate that with opencms . Actually when i am trying to generate container page in English then it's creating page in Punjabi language. Can some one tell me how i have to do that.
second question is while i am trying to change my folder name in opencms workplace then it's giving error 
 Runtime error in JPA layer:  org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceException

Please help me .

Answer (score 0):

I have a few questions, the language you want is in the workplace? or the text onlie/offline?

For the wokplace
you just have to chage your language preferences.

For the pages:
I guess your cms is set on English and Punjabi. So you have to search for the porperty locale or locale-availabe (the second one is for change between languages in the elements) in the container page or folder set the locale "en".